# QMessageBox and tabOrdering

Tags: qt, tabindex, qmessagebox

Is there any way to `setTabOrder` in `QMessageBox` without subclassing it or writing my own? In cases when you already got big project - this might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to setTabOrder in QMessageBox without subclassing it
>   or writing my own? In cases when you already got big project - this
>   might be useful.

There is a way to use `setTabOrder` in `QMessageBox`. All you need is `QWidget*` pointers to 'from' and 'to' tabs.

```
class MyApp
{
   // ...
   void tabOrdering();
   QMessagebox* m_pMsgBox; 
}

void MyApp::tabOrdering()
{
     auto* pSaveBn = m_pMsgBox->addButton(QMessagebox::Save);
     m_pMsgBox->setTabOrder(m_pMsgBox->defaultButton(), pSaveBn);
}
```

You may also consider using [QObject::findChild](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild) method for finding tab widget stops.